# Need to get my hands dirty on reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have read about Java Reflections but till date it has been a vague concept to me. Can someone give a brief details with short example on how to use reflections in Java ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html ?

Comment: +1 for the link.  The tutorial is very self-explanatory.

Comment: @Bragaadeesh: here's one example of a question I asked where the solution consists in the use of a tiny bit of reflection to detect if a method exists or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448614/java-easiest-way-to-package-both-java-1-5-and-1-6-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read about Java Reflections but
>   till date it has been a vague concept
>   to me.

Here is a quick into to reflection in java:

**Structural introspection**. Basic reflection deals with the introspection of object at run-time. This means that you can learn the structure of objects and classes at run-time programmatically, e.g. get the class of the object, list the methods of the class, list the fields defined in the class, etc.

**Reflective invocation and instantiation**. With reflection you can invoke a method at run-time which is not defined at compile-time, e.g. invoke method named M on object O, where M is read in a configuration file. You can also instantiate object dynamically without knowing the class at compile-time.

**Annotations**. Then you can move one level up in the meta levels, and play with annotations. [Annotations describe other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372876/how-and-where-are-annotations-used-in-java/1918154#1918154) such as class, method and fields. Many framework rely on this.

**Dynamic proxy**. [Dynamic proxy](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) can be generated at run-time. In this case, it's really like if you create a class dynamically at run-time. To use with care, but definitively handy and powerful in some cases.

I guess you will start with structural introspection. There are links to tutorials in the other answers, but I hope this gives you an overview of what else can be done.

Answer (score 2):

It's primarily to be used to access classes/methods/fields *programmatically* (i.e. during runtime instead of compiletime). Good real world API's which uses reflection intensively are ORM's like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org)/[JPA](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html).

You can find here a [Sun tutorial on the subject](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/) (click *Next* link at the bottom to paginate through it).

Answer (score 2):

I guess [the article 'Using Java Reflection' found on sun.com](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Something worth mentioning as well is [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/). Not only does it have reflective abilities, but it also allows run-time bytecode manipulation using ordinary source syntax! Once you've gotten into reflection a bit more (which you probably have by now), you'll truly appreciate it's beauty.